scrapy selenium firefox - cant scrap urls from a page
I am trying to get a list of urls from a website (perfectly permitted to scrape it).  I am using firefox and whilst it seemed to work last month does not work this month and i am struggling to see where the error is.
In the code below, the url_authority_list list is empty at the end.
the output i get is:
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2630883719752 on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2630883719752 acquired on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2630883914632 on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/urls\62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2630883914632 acquired on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/urls\62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2630883914632 on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/urls\62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2630883914632 released on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/urls\62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2630883719752 on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2630883719752 released on C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2024-06-29 14:30:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data> (referer: None)

the code is:
import scrapy  
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os

class foodstandardsagencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foodstandardsagency"
    allowed_domains = ["ratings.food.gov.uk"]
    start_urls = ["https://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data"]

    # will need a new token if using geckodriver
    os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = "ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


    def parse(self, response):
                            
        #create a list of urls
        url_authority_list = []
        
        for href in response.xpath('//tr/td/a[text()[contains(.,"English")]]/@href'):    
            url = urljoin('http://ratings.food.gov.uk/',href.extract())
            url_authority_list.append(url)
        
        print(url_authority_list)
        


maybe server changed something on page - to make it more modern - and now your code doesn't work.

how do you use firefox? Did you install module scrapy-selenium or similar? Standard scrapy doesn't use Selenium and it can't use Firefox - and it can't run JavaScript

BTW: there is good rule to use CamelCaseNames for classes - like FoodStandardsAgencySpider - it helps to recognize class in code. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

my guess is something changed between version changes in firefox for now

what does this have to do with firefox? and what page are you scraping? why not use the api?

The provided code doesn't use Selenium.
